# Keysi Fighting Method

Tags: self-defense, keysi-fighting-system

Is the *Keysi Fighting Method* studied exclusively by any military unit in the world or is it mixed with other military martial arts such as Krav Maga, Silat, etc?

Comment: well.. I just wanted to know whether there's any military unit that is training purely KFM or they mix it with other military martial arts such as krav maga, etc... Do I really have to ask them under 2 different questions?

Comment: Adding material from comments

Comment: On this note, most of the training I have seen is called basic/advanced hand to hand combat training with a military branch stamp on it...probably to hide the exact styles of combat from anyone else who might learn and counter specifically.  Governments like to proprietize their training programs.

Comment: Apparently the root KFM instructors have separated and created a new martial art called 'DNA fight science' which is an extended version of KFM governed under Defense Lab. I've watched few clips of defense lab that's been instructed around the world.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find any reference to a country's military training exclusively in the Keysi method. That said, I have yet to find any reference to a military officially using any part of KFM outside of sites associated with the style who claim that it's "used by military and security forces", which makes me wonder if it's used officially at all.

On further poking around for quotes, I can't even find much mention of it being used in the military from the Keysi sites, largely people claiming that it's aimed at military usage and people mentioning that their Keysi instructor has military experience.

> - "[Internationally regulated program aimed at professional police, military and private security self defence...](https://keysiworld.com/programs)"
> - "[Apparently some KFM moves are being incorporated to MMA instruction and are being taught in some military forces for very close combat.](http://www.themodernsurvivalist.com/archives/1242)"
> - "My instructor offers KFM as one of the primary arts he teaches. .... His practical fighting foundation is based on his extensive combat background: US Naval Search & Rescue, Nuclear Weapons Security for the US Navy, Close-Quarters-Combat Instructor for Blackwater (now Xe), bodyguard for dignitaries in Iraq, and being a Master Officer for Virginia Beach. .... [He's a combat historian, and travels to different locations in the US and around the globe to teach combat seminars for law enforcement, military (I believe), and citizens](http://www.bullshido.net/forums/showthread.php?t=104762&s=cd946973fa81b238552a706735ff7cd0&p=2631582&viewfull=1#post2631582)."
> - "[KFM has also been contracted now by the military and law enforcement communities for training programs which have been specifically designed for these areas](http://www.worldwidedojo.com/reality-based/keysi-fighting-method/)."

Comment: Do you have any reference links?

Comment: @mutt: It's hard to cite a negative, but I've added a handful of quotes that make it sounds like Keysi might be used in military contexts somewhere. The pickings are slim there.